# How to dedup email addresses in a data extension and put them into another data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm trying to figure out how I can take an existing data extension and create a query that dedups that data extension, and puts the dudupped records into another data extension.

I think SELECT DISTINCT is the route to take.  Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyDataExtension
WHERE Email in (SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM MyDataExtension)
```

Would this work?  And if so, how do I then output this to a new Data Extension?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mention if all of the column values are the same for the duplicates, because if not, that would dictate how your query is written.

I'd probably write it like this:

```
select
x.email
, x.field2
, x.field3
, x.field4 
from (
  select distinct 
  d.email
  , d.field2
  , d.field3
  , d.field4
  , row_number() over(partition by d.email order by d.field2) as rowNum
  from MyDataExtension as d
) x
where x.rowNum = 1
/* target: MyNewDataExtension */
/* action: overwrite */
```

This query will group rows by email address and assign them a number based on the sort order of `d.field2`.  Then in the `where` clause you pick just the first one in `d.field2` order for each email address.

**Also, using wildcards in SFMC is not a good idea.**  There's some caching of column names that will come back and bite you if you add new columns.

If the DE only has an email address column then it'd be as simple as:

```
select distinct
email 
from MyDataExtension 
/* target: MyNewDataExtension */
/* action: overwrite */
```

Comment: Awesome answers! The DE has two fields, contact ID and email address.  The contact ID is unique. I don't really care which contact ID is used, just want to make sure I am returning only one email address when there are dups.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min(ID) as ID, EmailAddress
FROM DataEx
GROUP BY EmailAddress
```

This query dedupe emails and bring the lower ID for each e-mail.